# Bash on Ubuntu on Windows logging bash sessions

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows-10, bash, terminal

My professor wants us to log our bash sessions by submitting a log of our bash (terminal) session. I am using Bash on Ubuntu on Windows with the Windows 10 Creator's Update.

When using the command "script test.log" I get:

> Script started, file is test.log
>
> script: cannot set signal handler: Function not implemented

At this point I am unable to see what I type and normally I would need to issue the "exit" command to save the script file, but that just closes the bash (terminal) window.

[Picture as well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AdARp.png)

Comment: It appears what your attempting to use isn't yet implemented in WSL.  Which means you won't be able to use WSL to do what your professor wants

Comment: Ahh ok, I guess since no one else was getting this error this was the only conclusion. I'll keep this question open for a bit to see if anyone has a way of doing it!

Comment: Can't you just use a virtual machine instead?

Comment: @SpiderPig yes this was what i was going to do if this was not possible.

Comment: btw. mingw or cygwin should work as well.

Comment: have you tried `bash 2>&1| tee bash.log` inside a bash session?

Comment: @EugenRieck this works for me but only shows the command output - not the command itself.

Comment: An alternative might be to use screen?  Maybe something like `screen -L -RD`?

Answer (score 0):

You could try getting your terminal to dump its output to a log.  xterm (for example) can enable logging all output to a file with `xterm -l`.

Or, if you have emacs, you can open Esc-x shell, and you'll get all the output.  Save the contents to a file C-x C-s {filename}.